# Picture in Picture from AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, avkit

I'm trying to support Picture in Picture for my iOS app and I need to display the content of a view, not a video. So I tried to use a library to record a view and show the video in a `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`. It works, the content of the view is displayed in the buffer display layer, but when I try to use PIP, only a loading indicator is shown. Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import AVKit

class View: UIView {
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer.self
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVPictureInPictureSampleBufferPlaybackDelegate {
    
    func pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, setPlaying playing: Bool) {
        
    }
    
    func pictureInPictureControllerTimeRangeForPlayback(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) -> CMTimeRange {
        .init(start: .zero, duration: self.buffers.first?.duration ?? .indefinite)
    }
    
    func pictureInPictureControllerIsPlaybackPaused(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) -> Bool {
        false
    }
    
    func pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, didTransitionToRenderSize newRenderSize: CMVideoDimensions) {
        
    }
    
    func pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController, skipByInterval skipInterval: CMTime, completion completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: View!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    var pipController: AVPictureInPictureController?
        
    var glimpse: Glimpse!
    
    var isRecording = false
    
    var buffers = [CMSampleBuffer]()
    
    @IBAction func pip() {
        pipController?.startPictureInPicture()
    }
    
    func startRecording() {
        glimpse = Glimpse()
        glimpse.startRecording(textView, withCallback: { url in
            if let url = url {
                do {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        (self.playerView.layer as! AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer).flush()
                        
                        if self.pipController == nil {
                            self.pipController = AVPictureInPictureController(contentSource: .init(sampleBufferDisplayLayer: self.playerView.layer as! AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, playbackDelegate: self))
                            self.pipController?.requiresLinearPlayback = true
                        }
                    }
                    
                    let reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: AVAsset(url: url))
                    let output = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: reader.asset.tracks.first!, outputSettings: nil)
                    reader.add(output)
                    reader.startReading()
                    
                    while let buffer = output.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                        self.buffers.append(buffer)
                    }
                    
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        })
        
        isRecording = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        var i = 0
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.textView.text += "Hello World! (\(i))\n"
            if self.isRecording {
                self.glimpse.stop()
                self.startRecording()
            }
            i += 1
        })
        
        let layer = playerView.layer as! AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer
        layer.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: .global()) {
            if let buffer = self.buffers.first {
                layer.enqueue(buffer)
                self.buffers.remove(at: 0)
            }
        }
        
        startRecording()
    }
}
```

In this example, I modify the content of a UITextView every second and I record a video of it. Then I extract the `CMSampleBuffer`s to display them in the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`.

I attached two screenshots, the first shows how the content of the text view is successfully shown in the `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` and the second shows how nothing is displayed when PIP is enabled.

[image: PIP Disabled]

[image: PIP Enabled]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced the same behavior when returning incorrect time range for playback. Make sure you return `.positiveInfinity` for duration otherwise your layer will be covered with the loading indicator.

```
    func pictureInPictureControllerTimeRangeForPlayback(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) -> CMTimeRange {
        return CMTimeRange(start: .negativeInfinity, duration: .positiveInfinity)
    }
```

Documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avpictureinpicturesamplebufferplaybackdelegate/3750337-pictureinpicturecontrollertimera?changes=la

Comment: Thank you very much, had the same issue because I used indefinite rather than positiveInfinity
`public static let indefinite: CMTime /*! @constant kCMTimeIndefinite
             Use this constant to initialize an indefinite CMTime (eg. duration of a live
             broadcast).
`

Comment: Thank you! I had stubbed in CMTime.zero and that also caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this working in Secure ShellFish and it made a difference how the CMSampleBuffers was created.

I had to create the CMSampleBuffer from a CVPixelBuffer that was IOSurface compatible and I had to mark the CMSampleBuffer with kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this later